# Java BMI Calculator

Tags: java, homework, eclipse

I'm learning java this week.
Please reviews my code for BMI calculator using java, need some your feedback. Thanks before!

This Assignment:

[image: BMI Calculator and expected output]

**My code**

```
public class bmiCalculator extends ConsoleProgram {
public void run() {
    println("Person 1's information: ");
    bmiCalculation(70.0, 194.25);
    
    println("");
    
    println("Person 2's information: ");
    bmiCalculation(62.5, 130.5);
    
    println("");
    
    print("Have a nice day!");
    
    }
public void bmiCalculation(double height, double weight) {
    
    // bmi algo = BMI = weight / height ** 2 * 703
    
    double newHeight = 1;
    double bmi = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i ++) {
        newHeight *= height;
    }
    bmi = weight / newHeight * 703;
    println(bmi);
    classifications(bmi);
    
}
public void classifications(double bmi) {
    if(bmi <= 18) {
        println("class 1");
    }
    else  if(bmi <= 24.9) {
        println("class 2");
    }
    else if(bmi <= 29.9) {
        println("class 3");
    }
    else {
        println("class 4");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You've hard coded the people's information, rather than prompting the user for it from the console. Since it's in the problem description it's probably part of what you're being assessed on.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void bmiCalculation(double height, double weight) {

  // bmi algo = BMI = weight / height ** 2 * 703

  double newHeight = 1;
  double bmi = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i ++) {
      newHeight *= height;
  }
  bmi = weight / newHeight * 703;
  println(bmi);
  classifications(bmi);
}
```

Seems overly complicated to me. You can one line it (and maybe move it to its own method):

```
bmi = (weight * 703) / (height * height);
```

Your output seems off with the assignments table, it mentions < 18.5:

```
public void classifications(double bmi) {
    if(bmi <= 18) {
        println("class 1");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other comments, I would suggest a change in the way you structure this program. Your functions that perform calculations and then print the output will be difficult to write automated tests for. As a first pass, I would modify your `classifications` function to return a `String`, and then perform the `println` from the calling function. You can then go one step further, and refactor to move all of the `println` calls into the `run` method, leaving you with two pure functions that take arguments and return a calculated result, without any side-effect behaviour.